# The <picture> Element in html5 shows not different images by resize

Tags: html, image, responsive-design

I found this code : 
https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_images_picture

I have tried it on all my browsers and it's been working properly. But I when I copy the code and I resize my browser, Only img tag is shown. Thanks for any help.

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body>

    <picture>
       <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="Blume 1.jpg">
       <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="Blume 2.jpg">
       <img src="Blume 3.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
    </picture>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use image source properly

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

<picture>
   <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_pink_flowers.jpg">
   <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_white_flower.jpg">
   <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
</picture>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. With your URLs/Sources workes now. But the code work not with the my own images from my local computer. I don't know, why.

Comment: @shimaamini can you show the image source of local what you have tried

Comment: The images are in the same folder like html file. I wrote just so : srcset="Blume 1.jpg" for picture tag and src="Blume 3.jpg" for img tag.

Comment: I thought you mostly doing mistake in `srcset` url, try to drag the image source to srcset.[file path may be something like this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found the mistake. In the name of the file there were spaces. I changed the names. without space workes.

Answer (score 4):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

<h2>The picture Element</h2>

<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="https://www.abc.net.au/news/image/8281088-16x9-940x529.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="https://static-news.moneycontrol.com/static-mcnews/2018/12/Google-770x433.jpg">
  <img src="https://www.irishtimes.com/polopoly_fs/1.3722378.1544095168!/image/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/box_620_330/image.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
</picture>

<p>Resize the browser to see different versions of the picture loading at different viewport sizes.
The browser looks for the first source element where the media query matches the user's current viewport width,
and fetches the image specified in the srcset attribute.</p>

<p>The img element is required as the last child tag of the picture declaration block.
The img element is used to provide backward compatibility for browsers that do not support the picture element, or if none of the source tags matched.
</p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The picture element is not supported in IE12 and earlier or Safari 9.0 and earlier.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried the same example and it's working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to use the `media` attribute just for providing images for multiple resolutions, use the `srcset` attribute instead.

If you resize the screen to a small width, the browser won't pick up a smaller image if a larger image is available in the cache. But the browser will choose the correct source properly for different device widths.

If you want to check if the `srcset` attribute is working properly, you can disable the cache in devtools and force the browser to load different sources by resizing the screen.